# Building an Angular Directive with an ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use an Angular Directive for my Forms and based on the Attributes it should use an Input Tag or a Select Tag. I tried to do this with an ng-if:
 -> If the select-options Attribute is set use a Select Tag
By using the ng-if in the Template of the Directive the Databinding to the model becomes somehow one-way. (i think the whole approach doing this by ng-if is wrong?)

Here is an Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
Parent: <input type="number" ng-model="data.a"/><br>
Data.a: {{data.a}}<br/>
Data.b: {{data.b}}<br/>
InputDirective: <my-directive ng-model="data.a"></my-directive>
SelectDirective: <my-directive ng-model="data.b" select-options="{'aa':'Two As','bb':'Two Bs'}"></my-directive>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.directive('myDirective', function()
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                value: '=ngModel',
                selectOptions: '='
            },
            template: '<input ng-if="!selectOptions" type="number" ng-model="value"/><select ng-if="selectOptions" ng-model="value" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in selectOptions"></select>'
        };
    });

    app.controller("AppController", function( $scope )
    {
        $scope.data = {
            a: 54,
            b: 'aa'
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure about this, but ng-model is special attribute, try using some other attribute to pass the value and assign it to ng-model

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: in the template change
    ng-model="value"
to
    ng-model="$parent.value"

ng-if is creating a child scope and it is creating this kind of problem https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

i still dont know if ng-if is the right aproach to this.

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thank you!